# how to solve: HSI to RGB conversion that lead to RBG color that is more than 255

Tags: php, image-processing, computer-vision, rgb

Edit: Thank you everyone who helped but the problem still persist. So, is there any better formula to edit saturation without needing clamping? Non linear formula might work but I don't know exact good formula. Thx

I am trying to develop a photo editing system that allow people to increase and decrease hue/saturation/lightness which is similar to what ipiccy.com does. 
I am using HSI<->RGB conversion. 
First, each pixel are convert from RGB to HSI.
 Secondly, user specify the amount of saturation she wants to add.
 Thirdly, system add  user's specified value to original saturation value converted in first step and then convert these HSI value to RGB. 
My problem is that when I convert new HSI value back to RGB, some of the RGB values are more than 255. So, colors  are not displayed properly.

I have been reading and trying for days but no luck in getting right. Anyone know how to solve it? Any clue or any link to read or solution is welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey we just met you, and this is crazy, we don't have crystal balls, so show your code, maybe?

Comment: This is quite common with color manipulations. You need to clip or clamp the individual values. My own C++ code for it is at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fastest-way-to-clamp-an-integer-to-the-range-0-255

Comment: hey, thx. Code added. Ya. I read at a lot of sources that it is common but I couldn't find solution at all and I didn't have lucky guess so far. :(

Comment: Not very long time ago I was in the exact situation with PHP (different use case though). I'll dig through my files and get you the optimized function.

Comment: So show us what have you tried? What was the input? What was the new Saturation value? What was the output?

Answer (score 1):

> No need to delete. The code indeed is badly formatted, but thanks for providing it!

This code was sent to me by some other guy working on the same issue with me, I've received it in the exact form I'll give it to you. All I did was to implement it in my code, so please forgive the bad answer.

[Here's the code](http://pastebin.com/SHVHa8nY) (3 functions)

`gimmeHSL()` will convert from RGB to HSL

> IN: R, G, B <=> {0, 255}, {0, 255}, {0, 255}
>
> OUT: H, S, L <=> {0, 360}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}

`gimmeRGB()` will convert from RGB to HSL

> IN: H, S, L <=> {0, 360}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}
>
> OUT: R, G, B <=> {0, 255}, {0, 255}, {0, 255}

`magic_kristo()`, I have no idea what it does, but it seems to be used by the other two.

Here's an example of the usage

```
print_r(gimmeRGB(gimmeHSL(200,153,148)));
```

Note: Even if this was helpful please don't upvote it, I'd feel very bad. Just use it and maybe leave a comment if it works.

```
function gimmeHSL($zk0,$ns1=null,$wo2=null){if(is_array($zk0)&&sizeof($zk0)==3)list($tm3,$ns1,$wo2)=$zk0;
else $tm3=$zk0;$ck4=min($tm3,$ns1,$wo2);$pw5=max($tm3,$ns1,$wo2);$qe6=$pw5-$ck4;
$up7=($pw5+$ck4)/510;if(0 ==$qe6){$li8=0;$wu9=0;}else{if(0.5>$up7){$wu9=$qe6/($pw5+$ck4);}else{$wu9=$qe6/(510-$pw5-$ck4);}
if($pw5==$tm3){$li8=($ns1-$wo2)/(6.0*$qe6);}
else if($pw5==$hd10){$li8=1/3+($wo2-$tm3)/(6.0*$qe6);}else{$li8=2/3+($tm3-$ns1)/(6.0*$qe6);}
if(0>$li8)$li8+=1;if(1<$li8)$li8-=1;}$li8=round($li8*360);return array($li8,$wu9,$up7);}
function gimmeRGB($np11,$vs12=null,$pp13=null){if(is_array($np11)&&sizeof($np11)==3)list($zg14,$vs12,$pp13)=$np11;
else $zg14=$np11;if($vs12==0){$tm3=$ns1=$wo2=round($pp13*255);}else{if($pp13<=0.5){$oo15=$pp13*($vs12+1);}
else{$oo15=$pp13+$vs12-$pp13*$vs12;}$qw16=$pp13*2-$oo15;$qk17=$zg14/360;$tm3=magic_kristo($qw16,$oo15,$qk17+1/3);
$ns1=magic_kristo($qw16,$oo15,$qk17);$wo2=magic_kristo($qw16,$oo15,$qk17-1/3);}return array($tm3,$ns1,$wo2);}
function magic_kristo($qw16,$oo15,$qk17){if($qk17<0)$qk17+=1;else if($qk17>1)$qk17-=1;
if(6*$qk17<1)$sx18=$qw16+($oo15-$qw16)*$qk17*6;else if(2*$qk17<1)$sx18=$oo15;else if(3*$qk17<2)$sx18=$qw16+($oo15-$qw16)*(2/3-$qk17)*6;
else $sx18=$qw16;return round(255*$sx18);}
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you alter the saturation value. If you do a simple add, then you absolutely must employ clamping, i.e. truncate over-255 values to 255. And the same for sub-zero values.
This will lead some colors to overlap.
You could also employ different formulas to make overflowing more difficult, but this might lead to behavior the user doesn't understand.
fact is, when you change a picture, information loss due to truncation is almost a given.
I'd try to warn the user and offering an undo function: e.g. showing oversaturated areas as white or magenta or blinking, as some cameras do.
Keeping the user from causing info loss would limit user interaction too much, IMHO.

Comment: Hi, thx for explanation but I am still pretty lost since I am quite new to image editing stuff. Initially, I try to set all RGB values more than 255 to be 255. It works for hue but for saturation, I can still see wrong colors.

Comment: The code you posted has an error, in that you pollute $x which is your loop counter. That might be why you get an infinite loop. Other than that, the logic seems correct. I have some doubts on performance and would suggest you checked out the imagemagick functions.

Comment: Hi iserni, ya. It's quite slow. I am using php gd and didn't find any function that just allow me to do saturation by typing imagefilter.saturation etc. Does imagemagick has it? I cannot use third party script as it is school project.

Comment: iMagick has the drawback of not always being installed (it's not bundled with PHP), but it's very optimized. As for the features, check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php and prepare to be amazed :-)